# JSPG0005E: tld file could not be found for uri[http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk] prefix [x]

Tags: jsf-1.2, websphere-7, tomahawk, tld

i m using jsf 1.2 and rich faces 3.3.2. While tying to deploy my application on websphere 7 server , i recieved following error

```
JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /pages/summary/summary.jsp:  
/pages/summary/summary.jsp(0,1) --> JSPG0005E: tld file could not be found for  
uri[http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk] prefix [x]
```

what is possible cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. the issue was that tomahawk12-1-1.jar file was missing in the production server. copied that and it was clean.